# not able to connect to Atlas database from strapi project

Tags: node.js, strapi, mongodb-atlas

I am new to strapi framework. I came to know that strapi and atlas are together now. I am able to connect to atlas account from my local terminal but not able to connect from strapi project, getting below error. I saw old topics in stackoverflow discussing about the same error but strapi has been upgraded and database configurations seems to be changed and none of those solutions are working.

[2020-05-20T12:57:23.957Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2020-05-20T12:57:23.959Z] error Make sure your MongoDB database is running..

Below is the content of config/environemnts/development/database.json

```
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "strapi-hook-mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mongo",
        "host": "cluster0-58gdw.mongodb.net",
        "srv": "true",
        "port": 27017,
        "database": "brewhaha",
        "username": "temp123",
        "password": "temp123"
      },
      "options": {
        "authenticationDatabase": "",
        "ssl": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a mongodb atlas i suggest to use settings.uri

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "mongoose",
      "settings": {
        "uri": "mongodb://paulbocuse:<password>@strapidatabase-shard-00-00-fxxx6c.mongodb.net:27017,strapidatabase-shard-00-01-fxxxc.mongodb.net:27017,strapidatabase-shard-00-02-fxxxc.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=strapidatabase-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority"
      },
      "options": {
        "ssl": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Follow all steps outlined in, to get your "uri":
https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/databases.html#install-on-atlas-mongodb-atlas

Answer (score 0):

For Strapi 3.4.6. Go to `config/database.js` try the following configuration.

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'mongoose',
      settings: {
        host: env('DATABASE_HOST', 'clusterX.XXXXX.mongodb.net'),
        srv: env.bool('DATABASE_SRV', true),
        port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 27017),
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'mydb'),
        username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'username'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'password'),
      },
      options: {
        authenticationDatabase: env('AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', null),
        ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', true),
      },
    },
  },
});
```